# react-jsonschema-form How to pass down additional props to Form

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-jsonschema-forms

I am using react-jsonschema-form with @rjsf/antd (Ant Design).

Off of Ant Designs Form component, they have a property named `size` which as the name suggests, controls the size of the different input fields (`Form.Item`).

https://ant.design/components/form/#Form

I am wanting to include the `size` property off of react-jsonschema-form's `Form` property. I was hoping that react-jsonschema-form's `Form` would pass down any additional props to the Ant Design `Form` but that doesn't seems to be the case.

How would I go about including `size`?

Appreciate the help!

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-poitras-jdshu0?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You should use `_internalFormWrapper` prop, as versions < 5 of RJSF.

```js
import { Form as AntdForm } from 'antd';
import { withTheme } from '@rjsf/core';
import { Theme as AntDTheme } from '@rjsf/antd';

interface MyComponentProps { size: 'small' | 'middle' | 'large' }

const MyComponent = ({ size, ...props }: MyComponentProps): JSX.Element => {
  function MyAntdForm() {
    return <AntdForm size={size} />;
  }

  const Form = withTheme<FormValues>(Theme);

  return <Form {...props} _internalFormWrapper={MyAntdForm} >
}
```